# Perspective Projection Matrix in OpenGL appears black

Tags: opengl, haskell, matrix, projection

I am attempting to implement a perspective projection transformation using Haskell and OpenGL.

My vertices are set up as follows:

```
  let vertices =
        [ -0.3,  0.3,  0, -- Front Top Left 0                         
           0.3,  0.3,  0, -- Front Top Right 1 
           0.3, -0.3,  0, -- Front Bottom Right 2             
          -0.3, -0.3,  0, -- Front Bottom Left  3 
           0.3, 0.3,   0, -- Back Top Left      4            
           0.3,   0,   0, -- Back Top Right     5               
           0.3,   0,   0, -- Back Bottom Right  6              
           0.3, 0.3,   0  -- Back Bottom Left   7  ]
```

and, using no transformation, or just the View transformation, everything appears as it should (a grey square).

The view transformation is

```
 view = [cos ty * cos tz,    cos tz * sin tx * sin ty - cos tx * sin tz,         cos tx * cos tz * sin ty + sin tx * sin tz,    -cx,
         cos ty * sin tz,    cos tx * cos tz + sin tx * sin ty * sin tz,    -1 * cos tz * sin tx + cos tx * sin ty * sin tz,    -cy,
         -1 * sin ty,        cos ty * sin tx,                                    cos tx * cos ty,                               -cz,
         0,                  0,                                                  0,      1]
```

where `(cx, cy, cz)` are the camera's position and `(tx, ty, tz)` are the cameras rotation about the axis in radian Euler angles.

---

The problems occurs when I apply the perspective transformation

```
perspective = [scale,     0,                        0,                     0,
                   0, scale,                        0,                     0,
                   0,     0, -1 * (far + near) / diff,                    -1,
                   0,     0,   -2 * near * far / diff,                     0]
```

where `diff = far - near` and `scale = 1.0 / tan (fov / 2.0)` and `fov = 0.785`.

My far and near planes are 10 and 0.01, respectively.

Once applied, using the following GLSL code, nothing appears (ie. only a black screen).

```
void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = perspective * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

I have tried viewing the square from multiple different angles and positions, and with culling disabled.

What is wrong with my perspective projection matrix or the application of it?

Comment: Looks like the projection matrix is transposed, see [equation 4.5](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20The%20Matrix%20Has%20You.html).

Comment: The matrices are expected to be sent to OpenGL in column major order. The projection matrix seems correct in this case.

Comment: That being said, the view matrix does seem to be transposed.

Comment: @Mokosha Yeah you're right. I find the formatting makes it tempting to think otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - the View matrix was transposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by transposing the view matrix.